# 775 Motor with 9V 1 Ampere adapter

Tags: dc-motor

I am trying to run a small fan I had created using 775 motor. There is no rating, mark anything on that motor.
I tried running with a old unused 9V bike battery and it runs too fast.

So I end up using 1 Ampere 9V adapter (cheap 1 dollar) and it runs good enough. Now the adapter seems to heat. I can touch sort of bit warm. Is it safe? I know that the current requirement for 775 motor is high but can it damage the adapter.

As per me I cannot use L298N motor driver as the 775 motor can fry it but does this apply to adapters as well? Some alternative to use less current for 775 motor something like 5watt resistor? But how to guess the resistance of motor?

Apologies for poor understanding about how these things work,

Comment: Probably few of us are going to know what a "755 motor" is so you should include a link to its datasheet. That will tell you its rated voltage current and, if it's any good, the required starting current. From those details you can start to specify a suitable power supply.

Comment: @Transistor Sorry it is 775 motor not 755. It is available like on any small shop here who sells switches, sockets etc. These are clone models so no spec sheet. Don't even know RPM as well.

Comment: They're usually rated 1.2A @ 12V, 0.5A at no load, 15A at stall. A 9V 1A supply will probably be at peak and/or burn out. I would get a different power supply (12V 2A or so).

Comment: @KristoferA - So they do burn out like 1A motor controller? So what you think what should I use to run it slow?

Comment: It depends on the load and voltage. Do you have a multimeter or ampere meter? That will tell you how much it pulls with the load (fan) you have attached to it.

Comment: Yes with a fan attached - the multimeter is showing 1.21A first and then end with 1.16 continuously. When I ran it with a 4AH bike battery and charge controller it was like 5/6 times faster and objective is to run slow.

Comment: That is going to be a problem for your 9V 1A power supply. Since those motors are built for a wide range of voltages (typically anywhere between 6-18V), a cheap solution may be a 10Ω, 12Ω, or 15Ω 10W resistor in series. That should slow it down a bit and reduce the current.

Comment: @KristoferA great have some Resistors of 5 watts. Will try with them and see will it be good enough to get started.